# member functions of a C++ class and link to them explicitly through dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, dll

I have to access member variable of a class inside a Dll, i have loaded the dll, but how to access the member variable of the class, i dn't want to use the virtual table concept used in COM. any input will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

`dllimport` means the implementation will be imported :

```
class __declspec(dllimport) YourClass
{
   // ... declarations ...
};
```

Useful link:

[HowTo: Export C++ classes from a DLL](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28969/HowTo-Export-C-classes-from-a-DLL)